# How does "insert into select" work with huge amount of data

Tags: sql, sql-server, deadlock

I have the query

```
INSERT INTO A SELECT ... FROM B JOIN C on B.ID = C.ID
```

Will table B or C be locked?

If table B and C contains a huge amount of data and the query itself is executed for a few minutes, is it possible to execute (select, insert, delete) a request for tables B or C?

What is the fundamental difference between this request?

```
INSERT INTO A SELECT ... FROM B JOIN C WITH (nolock) on B.ID = C.ID
```

Comment: depends on isolation level, but in general large inserts or deletes are often better done in batches...

Comment: See [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/) for the risks.

Comment: By default the target table will get a Write lock and the source tables a Read lock.

Comment: The version with `NOLOCK` will read dirty or duplicate data, even data that wasn't committed. It will take *more* locks itself while ignoring others' locks (hence the dirty/duplicate data). It can also fail because the source data was modified.

Comment: `NOLOCK` never fixes anything. Use [Snapshot Isolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server) to allow others to modify the source data while still reading it. Use SSIS to read and write data using different connections, buffering, batching.